# Generating install script for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I've Googled, I've searched, but I couldn't find an answer to this.

I've written a pretty big application with the framework CodeIgniter. Now, it's almost ready, and therefore almost ready to ship.

How do I install it on our server, or on our customers' servers?

I know I could write an installer for this, but I thought, maybe is there somebody who has written an installer generator. Or at least something that generates a script that can add 20-30 tables so that I don't have to spend a week building an installer. The application must be compatible with Oracle, MSSQL and MySQL.

It would be awesome if something like this is available.

edit: grammar
edit: I use the Active Record Class, so it's compatible with all databases.

Comment: First of all is your application compatible with all these databases?

Comment: Yes, I use Codeigniters Active Record Class, so it's compatible with almost every database.

Comment: installer generator?: hmm not sure what you mean? Creating a script for Mysql would be the easy part, just use phpmyadmin - export the db schema / data and then create a simple php script to install (or just phpmyadmin on the server). Also are you actually going to install the app on all 3 db's?

Comment: At this moment, we have two installations, one on a MySQL database and one on a MSSQL database. 
I know phpmyadmin can export a script, but I want a script that can install it not only for MySQL, but also for MSSQL and Oracle.
I know CI has a Database Forge Class that can do that, but, maybe it could be generated?

Comment: Installer generator: A script that can generate an installer script for an application. It can create a database, insert default data in it, and set settings in the config files.

Comment: JIRA, which is written in Java, utitizes the [Apache/OfBiz entity](http://ofbiz.apache.org/docs/entity.html) framework for database abstraction/persistence issues. I think Doctrine can do similar things, although it might be a bit late for that now.

Comment: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.installer.msi.php) also uses the [Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) to build their exe installer.

Comment: Well you could see about packaging your app up using something like http://www.phing.info/trac/. But I probabably think you after a more client side type installer. In which case I don't think there is a magic script out there for you, think you will have to get your hands dirty. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115652/php-installer-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: https://github.com/mikecrittenden/codeigniter-installer

Comment: Hi Schop, while this link you've posted may help solve the question today. If the link were to ever break, it won't be useful anymore. Consider making an [edit] to your answer to bring in some more details from the resource into the body of your answer. Since it's likely something the asker will need, you could explain why this is the correct answer and how this will help. This ensures that if the link ever breaks, your answer will still have value to future visitors. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need.
Does anyone know or it's possible to let's generate a installer for the database as well (using the CI Database Forge Class or something like that, so it will install on every kind of database)?

Comment: My installation module works all fine but as i list tables in the database just after the tables creations, it only shows one table. That is why My insert script also says database.table does not exist. Can any one let me know how to overcome this ? might be database cache thing or what